# Show that $P(X=c)=1 $for some constant c

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, also $X$ and $X-Y$ are independent. Prove that $$P(X=c)=1$$ for some constant c.

I tried using moment generating function, please give me some hints.

Comment: Can you show some of your work? I think moment generating functions (or characteristic functions) and using the definition of independence should work.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ have finite means and variances, then the zero covariances resulting from independence will imply that the variance of $X$ is zero. But you need rather more than this.

Comment: @user103828 Whoa. Do you really need mgfs? I think what Henry suggested is sufficient.

Comment: @Henry Do you? If var(X) = 0, then X is constant right?

Comment: Almost surely constant, i.e. with probability $1$

Comment: @LPS As Henry says assuming first and second moments exist then using variances works (and using mgfs is overkill) otherwise characteristic functions should work.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{E}X^2=\mathbb{E}X(X-Y+Y)=\mu_X(\mu_X-\mu_Y)+\mu_X\mu_Y=\mu_X^2\Rightarrow P(X=c)=1$ which follows from CS inequality.

Comment: There's something missing here, because it is assumed that the involved expectations are finite in order to deduce $EX^2 = \mu_X^2$ as finite values. What if some of the expectations are infinite? It seems like simply assuming that there are two different regions/points that $X$ can take on with positive probability and then deriving a contradiction is a more sound way to go.

Comment: Yes @user2566092, the assumption of existence of the first two moments of $X$ is used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch of a proof that does not require existence of moments. The characteristic function of $(X,X-Y)$ is
$$
E[e^{iXt+i(X-Y)s}]=E[e^{iXt}]E[e^{i(X-Y)s}]=E[e^{iXt}]E[e^{iXs}]E[e^{-iYs}]
$$
where the equalities follow by independence of $X$ and $X−Y$ and the independence of $X$ and $Y$. We also have by independence of $X$ and $Y$ that,
$$
E[e^{iXt+i(X-Y)s}]=E[e^{iX(t+s)}]E[e^{-iYs}]
$$
combining this (and noting that $E[e^{-iYs}]$ is nonzero in a neighborhood around the origin),
$$
E[e^{iXt}]E[e^{iXs}]=E[e^{iX(t+s)}]
$$
this implies that $X$ is independent of $X$ so it must be a constant (or equivalently we can use Cauchy's functional equation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation and continuity around the origin).